# class at runtime

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to create Java classes @ at runtime
(classes methods n variables), with using Java reflection API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that using reflection. You need a bytecode manipulation library, like [Jakarta BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/).

Comment: There is a nice example inside the tutorial. Take a look: http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/manual.html#HelloWorldBuilder .

Answer (score 3):

The standard Java API provides a set of static methods, that allows you to dynamically create a class that implements one (or many) interfaces.
Those methods are part of the class java.lang.reflect.Proxy.

Answer (score 3):

What do you require this for?

Interpreting the question in a very loose manor I can think of four likely options.

If you have a class that you add something too you might find that [Aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) is what you are really after.

If you have an interface that you want to dynamically implement (as posted by [barjak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673358/class-at-runtime/1673517#1673517)) what you want is [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html). This does not let create "code" at runtime but rather allows you link existing code to to a interface.

Finally (at three I know) you have actually building random classes at runtime. This you will need something like [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) or [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/). While there are cases when this is required it is IMO rare.

One other option is that you don't really *need* runtime but rather build time. In this case you might be able to use [annotations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) and [`apt`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/) (Java 5)  / [`Processor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) (Java 6).

Comment: +1 - was just about to say the same thing, generating byte code should only really be needed in very few situations.

Comment: I'd also add the scripting APIs (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) added in 1.6 but ultimately your decision is likely to be guided by how the behaviour of the 'class' is going to be defined.

Comment: I'd forgotten about the scripting API but yes that is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is.  You need a java.lang.Class instance initially, for the target class you wish to create.  Depending on your structure, this might either be passed in by a caller (if they're supplying the concrete class they want created), or you can statically access the class variable (e.g. `MyFooImpl.class`).

The simplest way is to call [Class.newInstance()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()).  This invokes the default, no-arg constructor (assuming there is one for the class; if not it throws an exception).

If you need to invoke a particular constructor with some argument, you need to call [Class.getConstructor()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) to get a Constructor instance, which you can then call [newInstance](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)) on.

In all cases you'll need to deal with reflection exceptions that you wouldn't get if invoking the constructor directly.

**Big edit**: I assume your question was about creating instances of a class via reflection.  However I'm beginning to think that you're asking about *defining* new classes through at runtime.  If so, then reflection won't help you here - you'd need to invoke a compiler programatically, which I believe can be done but I'm not 100% on the details.  I think you'd also have to go through some hoops to get the ClassLoader to pick up your new class too.

Comment: Yeah but this is for existing class to create objects from it, I want to create a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the source code string and compile it to an class file using [Janino](http://www.janino.net/).

Answer (score 0):

As people have already mentioned, there's no way of creating new classes at runtime using reflection. One library that I know is used by different mocking libraries and the likes is [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use javassist. here is sudo code

```
        javassist.ClassPool pool = new ClassPool(true); 
        CtClass bclass = pool.makeClass("brandnewclass);
        bclass.addConstructor(CtNewConstructor.defaultConstructor(bclass));
        CtClass[] fieldclasses = new CtClass[fields.length];
        CtClass serClass = pool.get(Serializable.class.getName());
        bclass.addInterface(serClass);
```

Class clazz = pool.loadClass("className");
obj = clazz.newInstance();

Use reflection to extract values from an existing class and assign values to new class. 
hope this helps. 
Gopi